# Django can't save parent id of child objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

I am tying to save parent id when the forms will be save  but I am not understanding where I am doing mistake. I am using  `<input type="hidden" name="parent" id={{i.sno}}>` for save parent id and I can see the id number if I inspect html from browser.

**models.py**

```
class Contact(MPTTModel):
       user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='contact_user')
       parent =TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            null=True, blank=True, related_name='contact_parent')
       sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,)
       #my others fields....
```

**forms.py**

```
class TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Contact
         fields = ['message','parent','sno','existing_customer','technical_service']
```

**views.py**

```
 def SupportPageView(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":
       support_form =  TicketForm(request.POST or None)
       if support_form.is_valid():
          isinstance = support_form.save(commit=False)
          isinstance.user = request.user
          isinstance.name = request.user.first_name 
          isinstance.email = request.user.email
          isinstance.save()
          name = request.user.first_name 
          messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, f'{name} Thanks for your message. We will get back to you very soon')   
          return redirect('contact:support-ticket')
    else:
      support_form = TicketForm()
          
    user = request.user
    support_object = Contact.objects.filter(user=user)
    

    context = {"support_form":support_form,'support_object':support_object}       
    return render(request,"contact/support.html",context)
```

**HTML**

```
 {%for i in support_object%}
   <form method="POST">
                        {%csrf_token%}
                        
                        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" style="height: 150px;"></textarea><br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="parent" id={{i.sno}}>
                         
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                    </form>
 {%endfor%}
```

my forms is saving as a parent but I want they will save as child.

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: Rvector read the question. I described everything's

Answer (score 1):

I was doing mistake in html fields

I was using  `<input type="hidden" name="parent" id={{i.sno}}>`

but it should be  `<input type="hidden" name="parent" id="parent_id"  value="{{i.sno}}">`. I was missing value in my html fields